# Как я могу извлечь посты из профиля Instagram с помощью python?

Tags: post, view, instagram, profile

Как извлечь посты, которыми поделился профиль Instagram, то есть изображения или видео с помощью Python? От аккаунта, чьи посты не отображаются. Итак, как я могу извлечь сообщения, подписку, подписчиков и истории с помощью python?